# Is there a way to avoid codegen List deletion when Optional type is used

Tags: java, graphql-codegen

I have this java's field :

```
Optional<List<String>> randomVar
```

And when i run a codegen the Typescript's result is:

```
InputMaybe<randomVar>
```

How can I avoid the List deletion?